# Передача аргументов в порожденный процесс и возвращение результата

Tags: c++, консоль

У меня есть программа с GUI и программа, которая выполняет алгоритм, она постоянно перекомпилируется. Возник вопрос, как мне из GUI передать в программу-алгоритм массив(можно по значениям), а затем вернуть такой же массив(тоже можно по значениям)?
Вызов программы из GUI:

```
np = Process::Start(Path + "\\f.exe");
<Получаю значение, возвращаемое вызванной программой и вывожу его>
```

Что-то вроде кода программы с алгоритмом:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "func.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    <Получаю массив>
    <Выполняю с ним все операции>
    <Возвращаю его программе с GUI>
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Самое универсальное (но не самое быстрое и даже не самое краткое с т.з. кодирования) решение это использовать stdin-stdout в порожденном процессе (т.е. парадигма фильтра, аналогичная конвейеру из пары команд в командной строке). Ваша основная программа создает 2 канала (pipe или сокет). Один связываете с stdin порожденного процесса, а другой с его stdout. В первый пишете свой массив из второго читаете результат. Такая схема достаточно легко адаптируется к удаленной обработке и в принципе готова для использования в неком графе фильтров, если потребуется такое изменение задачи

Comment: @avp, а можете написать совсем небольшой пример, как их можно таким образом связать?

Comment: Попробуйте сами. В простом случае вам понадобятся [pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html),  [fork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [dup2](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html), [execve](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [signal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html), [read/write/close/exit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) и [waitpid](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) (остальное посмотрите по ссылкам в этих manpages, кстати, во многих есть примеры использования)

Comment: Чуть не забыл. Вызывайте [fflush(stdout)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) перед fork, во избежании возможного удвоения части выводящихся сообщений (надеюсь, почему это может произойти понятно)

Comment: @ВадимЕрмаков - еще можно взять Qt и QProcess - эта штука сделает всю черновую работу по открытию процесса и присоединению потоков ввода-вывода. Вам останется только аккуратно обрабатывать приходящие сигналы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основных вариантов штук 5, а если учесть комбинации, счет пойдет на десятки - сотни. Почитайте какой-нибудь учебник по системному программированию вроде [Побегайло](http://fpmi.bsu.by/main.aspx?guid=25971) [*ISBN 5-94157-792-3*] (который является, фактически, пристойным переводом `MSDN`)

На вскидку, самый быстрый способ - это использовать расшаренную между  процессеми память (aka `mmap` в Линуксе и `MapViewOfFile` в форточке).

Причина, почему это быстро - потому что фактически, два процесса будут использовать одну и ту же физическую память - никакого копирования данных происходить не будет.

С другой стороны, наиболее брутальным, тормозным, но супер-переносимым, гибким и расширяемым, является перекачка данных через стандартные потоки ввода-вывода в формате `JSON`.

Гибкость получается огромная - потому что `JSON` могут переваривать огромное количество языков и библиотек. Можно наколхозить `GUI` на `Python`, а вычислитель - на плюсиках, и они без проблем подружаться.

Дальше идут всякие варианты с сокетами (локальными и TCP), использование `COM API` (так делает `DirectX`)) и прочее техническое творчество.

Что выбирать - решать вам, разумеется.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вот я тоже подумывал про использование физической памяти(ну там, файл), но решил, что будет слегка топорно. А ещё думал, что смогу использовать argv, но, видимо, файл действительно проще

Comment: @ВадимЕрмаков файл - это слишком топорно, расшаренная память не сильно сложнее в реализации